# FOSUserBundle for symfony 2.4.3

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, fosuserbundle

I want to start a new project on symfony 2.4.3 and I need the functionality of the fosuserbundle. My Problem: On their github (https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle) in the documentation they recommand 2.1.x.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19071161/install-fosuserbundle-in-symfony-2-3) , a user says you should install fosuserbundle manually but this question is for symfony 2.3.

Can I use the bundle on my version of symfony? If yes, can I install it with composer? If no, are there any similar bundles that I can use instead?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This version of the bundle requires Symfony 2.1+. If you are using Symfony 2.0.x, please use the 1.2.x releases of the bundle.

From [their docs](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md). 2.1+ means, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4, ... 2.n So 2.3 is perfectly valid.

Moreover, Composer handles the dependencies for you, so just require it and run `composer update`, if the Symfony version is not supported the command fails and you know it doesn't support your current version, if it succeeds everything is working perfectly.